# AppendChild($element) to an existing html element with php

Tags: php, html

I'm using the following PHP code in an attempt to append a form data into html tables (HTML file already exist as Customers.html).

```
<?php
  $myfile = 'Customers.html';
  $myfile = realpath($myfile);
  $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
  $doc->loadHTML($myfile);
  $doc->formatOutput = True;

  $table = $doc->appendChild($doc->createElement('table'));
  $tableRow = $table->appendChild($doc->createElement("tr"));
  $userName = $tableRow->appendChild($doc->createElement('th'));
  $doc->saveHTMLFile("Customers.html");
?>
```

The code executes fine but it dumps the generated html code outside the body tag. I want the table tag, created by PHP, to be appended as child of the body tag but the result is this:

```
<html>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I want is this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
       <tr>
         <th>
         </th>
       </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

How do i achieve it?

I don't want to create the body tag with php.

I tried to use

```
$body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body');
$table = $doc->createElement('table');
$body->appendChild($table);
```

and then append $table to it, it did not work.

Can someone please enlighten me what i'm doing wrong.

I'm new in PHP, just learning. 
Please tell me if more info is required.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show how you append table to it?

Comment: I have added 'How' i appended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
$table = $doc->createElement('table');
$body->appendChild($table);
```

Comment: :( Now it overwrites the previously made $tables. what can i do to stop it?